# Not able to install VS Python in MACOS

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010

I have installed Visual studio in my MacOS. Now when I install Python from that as extensions in /usr/bin/python path
python -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7

but that's Macs Python. I think Visual Studio has another Python version. Which I am not able to set up. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to select the interpreter you want inside Visual Studio Code. To do this, on Visual Studio press

`CTRL + shift + P`

and type

`Python: Select Interpreter`.

Finally, select your desired Python Interpreter from the list.